# Memory leaks - who to trust VLD vs MSVC

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-leak-detector

ALL,

I have MSVC 2017 and I have VLD installed.

Sometimes MSVC reports memory leaks, but VLD says "No memory leaks detected!"

Who is correct?

TIA!

Comment: Sometimes, MSVC reports *potential* memory leaks. Is this, perhaps, the issue?

Comment: @AdrianMole, that's surprising. I know `valgrind` reports potentials, but I never heard this about MSVC. My probem is that I have DLLs and passing the pointer from one to another, but deleting it in the end. So I guess this is the case. OTOH, does this mean I should trust VLD?

Comment: I've never used VLD, so can't really assess its trustworthiness. However, I also (generally) don't have problems with memory leaks in my code (even with cross-module pointer use).